# What is the best way for coordinating workers in tomcat cluster?

Tags: java, tomcat, cluster-computing

I am working with a web app that needs to be deployed in a tomcat cluster.  The app needs to occasionally send notifications.  The issue is that if the workers run uncoordinated, there is a chance more than one worker will send the notifications.  I need a way to coordinate so that only one worker at a time sends the notification.
My search lead to Zookeper, but it seems a bit involved (separate machines to run the ensemble, etc.)

Is this the best solution out there? Is there another solution that can run as a web app on the same tomcat servers hosting the worker nodes (I would like to reduce the system upkeep efforts)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a database?

If so, you could use that to synchronize the instances. Have a table with a row that you can use for locking.

That should work at least for reasonably small workloads.

Comment: Thanks Thilo, I do have a database.  I will look into row locking.